# Passing scope through deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm making an ajax wrapper with jQuery, but I'm having some problems handling the scope correctly. (code was shortened for readability)

I have a utility class I would like to use in the beforeSend event, but it's currently undefined. I tried using call() method to pass the scope down but this didn't change anything.

How could I achieve this ?

```
class AjaxHelper{
private _utils: Utilities;
AjaxCall(options: AjaxHelperOptions)
{
    this._utils = new Utilities();

    var defaults: AjaxHelperOptions = { ... };
    var settings: AjaxHelperOptions = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var deferred = $.Deferred.call(this, function (d) {

        d.done(settings.success);
        d.fail(settings.error);
        d.done(settings.complete);

        var jqXHRSettings = $.extend.call(this, {}, settings, {

            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            ______________________________________
            this._utils.CallSomeUtilityFunction();
            ______________________________________

                d.resolve;
            }

             .......................

            $.ajax.call(this, jqXHRSettings);
    });

    var promise: JQueryPromise = deferred.promise();

    promise.done = deferred.done;
    promise.fail = deferred.fail;

    return promise;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a lambda function like this:

```
beforeSend: (jqXHR, settings) => {
    this._utils.CallSomeUtilityFunction();
    d.resolve;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried: var deferred = $.Deferred((d) => {} and beforeSend: (jqXHR, settings) => {}, this had no effect unfortunatly.

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe there's something about beforeSend that the scope is set to something else.  The easiest thing to do is right after ```this._utils = new Utilities();``` you set ```var utilScope = this;``` and then you can use ```utilScope._utils.CallSomeUtilityFunction();```  That has to work.

Comment: I managed to make it work with the fat arrows, but I ended up using your second technique as my ajax call was getting the wrong scope. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain function `this` scope in the entire chain:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred.call(this, (d) => { // this line

        d.done(settings.success);
        d.fail(settings.error);
        d.done(settings.complete);

        var jqXHRSettings = $.extend.call(this, {}, settings, {

            beforeSend: (jqXHR, settings) =>  { // AND this line
            ______________________________________
            this._utils.CallSomeUtilityFunction();
            ______________________________________

                d.resolve;
            }

             .......................

            $.ajax.call(this, jqXHRSettings);
    });
```

Comment: My understanding was because he's using function.call in ```fxn.call(this, (d) => {return this.b * d; })``` and passing in ```this``` that the arrow function would be overkill.  What's the difference?